# Splitting a string up to a specific location

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I have a question and wondering how to address it with `sed`? How does one cut a variable up to a specific location, in my case `_g`?

#### Example

```
variable="This_is_good_g0r0s0_continues"
```

I need to cut this variable up to `_g`. I should also mention, the number of characters before `_g` is random.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with internal variable expansion operators in all POSIX shells :

```
variable="This_is_good_g0r0s0_continues"
up_to_first__g="${variable%%_g*}"
up_to_last__g="${variable%_g*}"
```

Comment: Although it is not important for this question, but as a good practise "please quote your variables on your answers on this site!". http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells. Sorry, couldn't resist ;)

Comment: @jimmij. You're right. Sounds like I'll have to fix my bad habits.

Comment: @jimmij [The right-hand side of an assignment is implicitly double-quoted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748). But it is a arguably pedagogically sound to quote anyway when posting answers here (especially because the quotes are necessary in seemingly similar cases such as `export foo="$bar"`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut at last `_g` then try the following:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)_g.*/\1/' <<< 'This_is_good_g0r0s0_continues'
This_is_good
```

If you want to cut at first `_g` then

```
$ sed 's/_g.*//' <<< 'This_is_good_g0r0s0_continues'
This_is
```

Comment: That assumes `$variable` doesn't contain newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

With a BRE - with `sed` - you can slice match sequences by counting their occurrence. I do not think that `sed` would be an ideal tool for slicing shell var values - the shell provides a fairly intuitive means of doing that already - but that is already covered.

BRE pattern sequences when multiplied will split to the right as far as they might. For example:

```
echo 0123456789 | sed 's/\([0-9]\)*/\1/'
```

...prints 9. It gets a little more useful when you split with actual counts though.

Another example:

```
echo _good _goroso _goes _gop |
sed 's/\(.*_g\)\{2\}/\1/'
```

...which gets...

```
oes _gop
```

This wont work like you might think, though - or at least it doesn't work like I expected when I started playing with it. You can't go back another `_g` there with `\{3\}` - not in this case anyway. The pattern is too variable `.*` matches everything - including nothing - and it is therefore difficult to easily quantify. What you *can* do is continue to split it:

```
echo _good _goroso _goes _gop |
sed 's/\(\(.*_g\)\{2\}\)\{2\}/\1/'
```

...which prints

```
oroso _goes _gop
```

Perhaps it is better to say *squeeze* than it is *split*. Here - by matching at least so many occurrences of a `.*` zero-or-more occurrence pattern I effectively limit its possible match - which will always be as greedy as it might. So I slice smallest piece by smallest piece off of the end of what it matches.

This is more easily seen by looking at the match itself - which can still be had in `&` in addition to the match that is had already in `\1`. I've often found such eccentricities useful, personally, though i wouldn't be surprised to learn I am alone in that. You might, for example, compound the match from each end like:

```
echo _good _goroso _goes _gop |
sed 's/\(\(.*_g\)\{2\}\)\{2\}/&\1/
```

...which prints :

```
_good _goroso _goes _goroso _goes _gop
```

...because the entire match for `.*_g` is in `&` but the subdivided pattern is only a portion.

...or even...

```
echo _good _goroso _goes _gop |
sed 's/\(\(.*_g\)\{2\}\)\{2\}/\2&\1/
```

...which shuffles every level of the match like...

```
oes _g_good _goroso _goes _goroso _goes _gop
```