# Cut a string up to a certain character

Tags: directory, path, split

I've searched the site and I've seen similar questions but I couldn't get them to work.  I tried to follow: [Splitting a string up to a specific location](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171308/splitting-a-string-up-to-a-specific-location) but it didn't work.  I working with Korn.

I mainly want the directory of a file passed in.  So the file would be:

```
/home/me/working/from/here/howareyou.txt
```

So I want to up get:

```
/home/me/working/from/here/
```

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
THEDIR="${1%//*}"
```

But it just spit out the whole parameter.
Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one slash

```
THEDIR="${1%/*}"
```

Slower but easier to remember is `dirname`.

Comment: Thank you.  It worked.  I would upvote but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score -1):

I like using cut, in association with rev.
Basicly, you pipe the full path of your file to rev, to reverse the string name.
Then, you pipe it to cut, with a "-" after the field number you want, and then, you reverse it again.

This results in something like that:

```
echo "$name" | rev | cut -d'/' -f2- | rev
```

If you don't know it yet, cut split the string around a delimiter char, indicated by -d, and select the field you want, indicated by -f (passing it 2 meaning that you want the second part of the string), adding a minus char meaning that you want it until the end of the string (not using minus would stop the string at the next occurrence of delimiter)

Comment: Can somebody explain why this is bad?

Comment: rev is not supported everywhere. I like the idea, nice trick, but I did not upvote (and somebody downvoted) since it is a lot of overhead.